# Google re2 namedcapture, how to parse results in c++?

Tags: c++, regex, re2

using google re2 library for regex i haven't found a way to parse results, anywhere!

this is a short example

```
bool b_matches ;
string s_teststr = " aaaaa flickr bbbb";
RE2 re("(?P<flickr>flickr)|(?P<flixster>flixster)");
assert(re.ok()); // compiled; if not, see re.error();
b_matches = RE2::FullMatch(s_teststr, re);

  b_matches = RE2::FullMatch(s_teststr, re);

// then,
re.NumberOfCapturingGroups() //-> always give me 2

 re.CapturingGroupNames(); //-> give me a map with id -> name (with 2 elements)

re.NamedCapturingGroups() //-> give me a map with name -> id (with 2 elements)
```

what i have to do to know that only flickr has been matched ?

thank you,

Francesco

--- after some more testing i didn't have found a soltuion for the namedcapture, only way thing i have found working give me the extracted text and is this.

```
string s_teststr = "aaa  hello. crazy world bbb";
std::string word[margc];
RE2::Arg margv[margc];
RE2::Arg * margs[margc];
int match;
int i;

    for (i = 0; i < margc; i++) {
        margv[i] = &word[i];
        margs[i] = &margv[i];
    }
   string s_rematch = "((?P<a>hello\\.)(.*)(world))|(world)";
  match = RE2::PartialMatchN(s_teststr.c_str(), s_rematch.c_str(), margs, margc);
cout << "found res = " << match << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < margc; i++) {
        cout << "arg[" << i << "] = " << word[i] << endl;
    }
```

-------- this will give me in output:

> found res = 1 arg[0] = hello. crazy
>   world arg[1] = hello. arg[2] =  crazy
>   arg[3] = world arg[4] =

to test with the second part of the string matching...

```
string s_rematch = "((?P<a>hello\\.d)(.*)(world))|(world)";
```

--- i get as output:

> foudn res = 1
>   arg[0] =
>   arg[1] =
>   arg[2] =
>   arg[3] =
>   arg[4] = world

my problem is taht the name capture --> a <--- never come out and the output should be cleared (lowercase in case of insensitive match, removed from added compatibily chars,.. ) and processed again against a map because i don't have the named capture which give me the key instead of the value for this preg

Comment: got it! the only way i've found to get my named capture is to parse the resutls args and when string length is > 0 then search for the arg id into  ----------------------------------------------------  const map<int, string>& m_RE_namedmap2 = re_compiled.CapturingGroupNames(); // -- id => name                               --------------------------------------                    this give me the keyword corresponding to the id found , than i have to create a new map with key (found searching for the id into the map of CapturingGroupNames and with the value which is the string with length > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a string to be populated upon success. For example:

```
std::string matchedValue;

if (RE2::FullMatch(s_teststr, re, &matchedValue))
{
    if (matchedValue.empty())
    {
        //not flickr
    }
}
else
{
    // matchedValue.empty() == true
}
```

Comment: yes but this didn't solve the problem, for example
if i have to parse "(?P<a>hello)|(?P<b>crazy)|(?P<c>world)" into "hello world" how matchedvalue can be usefull?  the matching of a string is simple using RE2 and it's a bit explained in theyr guideline, but i found no instructions for these "named match"

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are saying. If you have three capture groups just pass in three strings? Alternatively, if you have so many 'or's then you should probably consider using re2::set.

Comment: "If you have three capture groups just pass in three strings?" you mean to do 3 time the regexp match? it's almost 3 times heavyer and also this is an example in my working app this is a match witch 100+ different strings i'm moving from a huge multiple string.find statement to regexp and i have to know what string has been matched and also it will be used with multiple match, so i cannot do that with a simple string_match//string_results pair